# Как из Image сохранить изображение на прямую (по ссылке,расположению) без диалогового окна

Tags: wpf

В моем случае: Я загружаю картинку в Image , и мне нужно сохранить в конкретный каталог это же изображение ,чтобы потом когда открывалась программа ,это изображение уже отображалось

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: В том что я не знаю как это сделать , подробней : Мне нужно загрузить фото студента в Image для портфолио , и надо сохранить  это фото в определенную папку ,чтобы в дальнейшем  программа автоматически открывала это изображение .

Comment: Делайте сразу при выборе фото File.Copy(...)